# Expo Removing Permission from android manifest with config plugin

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I'm using [config plugin](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/) to modify the content `AndroidManifest` in an app with expo managed builds.

but it looks like it does not do anything.
here is my `app.config.js`

```js
import { AndroidConfig, withAndroidManifest } from "@expo/config-plugins";
const {

} = AndroidConfig.Manifest;
const {
  removePermissions,
} = AndroidConfig.Permissions;

const withCustomConfig = (config) => {
  config.name = "NEWNAME"
  return withAndroidManifest(config, async (config) => {
    config.modResults = await setCustomConfigAsync3(config, config.modResults);
    return config;
  });
};

async function setCustomConfigAsync3(config, androidManifest) {
  removePermissions(androidManifest,["android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"])
  return androidManifest
}

const config = {
  name: "TEST",
  plugins : [[withCustomConfig]],
  slug: "TEST",
  ...
}

export default config;
```

it creates a package with named `NEWNAME` so it means that the plugin is called, but nothing in `withAndroidManifest`'s action is called. I also tried to change other props of the `AndroidManifest` like `meta-data` but nothing is working there

i'm usig `expo build:android` to create the apk.

anyone has any idea that whats wrong with this pice of code?
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plugins are mostly meant to be used with `expo prebuild` (it generates android and ios folders that can be built with Android Studio and Xcode like any other Android or iOS app using your own hardware) or `eas build` commands

You can not use plugins with `expo build`

Reference:

1. https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/#plugin-module-resolution
2. https://blog.expo.dev/turtle-goes-out-to-sea-d334db2a6b60